# Source for Agents stopping

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to create a simulation of a basic traffic intersection in **AnyLogic**.

I have **North/South** direction with an **East/West** direction controlled by traffic light. When the simulation first runs the North/South direction has the **green** and the East/West direction has the **red**. I'm getting multiple cars from sources traveling North/South but only one car traveling from east/west which is waiting at the red light.  Only when the east/west light turns green and that car begins to go, do I get additional cars arriving into the model from east/west direction.

What I'm trying to do is have a queue of cars waiting at the east/west red stop light while north/south bound traffic traverse the green but I'm only getting one car in the east/west queue.

Comment: i made a video about this years ago: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgYqraEibD4

Comment: make your roads longer, I believe the Source only creates cars if they have enough space to do various manoevers.

Comment: Got it!  I did make my roads longer and incorporated Felipe's suggestion and everything is working as expected.  Thank you both!

Comment: Please mark this as solved then so others with the same question find it more easily in the future.